# Specific text to ROLLUP / Subtotals in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, rollup

I have following Query:

```
  SELECT REL_NR, ERR_CODE, COUNT (ERR_CODE)
  FROM ZDL_ERR
  WHERE ERR_CODE > 0
  GROUP BY ROLLUP (REL_NR, ERR_CODE)
  ORDER BY REL_NR DESC, ERR_CODE;
```

with following Output:

```
196 1148   16
196 1180 2288
196 1181  177
196      2481
```

Is there a way to give a ROLLUP a text so it displays something like this:

```
196 1148   16
196 1180 2288
196 1181  177
Subtotal 2481
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the `null` value you get that label in the second column:

```
SELECT   REL_NR, 
         COALESCE(TO_CHAR(ERR_CODE), 
           CASE WHEN REL_NR IS NULL THEN 'Grand Total'
                                    ELSE 'Sub Total'
           END) AS ERR_CODE,
         COUNT (ERR_CODE)
FROM     ZDL_ERR
WHERE    ERR_CODE > 0
GROUP BY ROLLUP (REL_NR, ERR_CODE)
ORDER BY REL_NR, ERR_CODE;
```

If you have `null` values in your `ERR_CODE` or `REL_NR` columns, then the following is a more correct way to do it:

```
SELECT   REL_NR,
         CASE GROUPING(ERR_CODE) 
             WHEN 1 THEN 
                 CASE GROUPING(REL_NR)
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'Grand Total'
                            ELSE 'Sub Total'
                 END
             ELSE TO_CHAR(ERR_CODE)
         END AS ERR_CODE,
         COUNT (ERR_CODE)
FROM     ZDL_ERR
WHERE    ERR_CODE > 0
GROUP BY ROLLUP (REL_NR, ERR_CODE)
ORDER BY REL_NR, ERR_CODE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use GROUPING clause. Code will look like:

```
SELECT DECODE(GROUPING(REL_NR),0,TO_CHAR(REL_NR),'Subtotal') REL_NR ...
```

Comment: This works fine (+1); it would just need some adjustment for recognising the grand total record.